# In the MCU, what can kill Thor and what cannot?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok*,  we have a lot of incongruity among what can kill Thor, what cannot, and what merely injures him.

Obviously he can take an immense beating.

But,

- We have Hela threatening to kill him.

> -  We have Hulk throwing him around like a rag doll
>  -  He falls from hundreds of feet in the air. 
>  -  He is crushed by all of Hulk's weigh.   Etc.

Yet on the other hand, we have

> several remarks by Thor about getting killed.   In particular, at one point Hulk throws a shield towards him in their quarters and he says something along the lines of "That could have killed me!"

In addition,

> he is susceptible to what appear to be electricity-based obedience tags.   (Isn't he the god of thunder?)

I get that a lot of it's played for action or comedic value, but

## Is there any consistent story in the MCU about what can kill/injure Thor and what cannot?

Comment: To be fair, the Hulk beat the living crap out of Thor, and he woke up having been healed by medics of some sort. It's not unreasonable to think that he may have been killed if the fight had gone on longer.

Comment: The kind of damage he took would be instant death for any mere human, but he gets up and keeps fighting. I don't think you can give the medics any credit here.

Comment: Same for when he beat the everloving $!@# out of Loki.

Comment: thor though as loki have (as asgardians) way stonger skin,.... and thus all survive quite a beating by human standards ;)

Comment: This question could do with a Thaddeus answer ...

Comment: We see dozens (if not hundreds) of Asgardians being killed by being stabbed and bludgeoned. What can kill him? Most things that would also kill a human.

Comment: @Valorum, I don't even get the point of your comment.    What bludgeoning killed other Argardians obviously is not evidence of what kills Thor since, you know, um, he was way more bludgeoned and didn't, you know, get killed.   Or if we construe that it is inconsistent, you'd have to assert that This is merely a typical Asgardian, which is also doubtful.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - He's wearing special armour and has a belt thingy that make him stronger and more impervious.

Comment: @Valorum -- well! -- if that's true, then that needs to get into an answer

Comment: @Valorum - If you’re talking about Ragnarok, they’re being killed by Hela and her magical hyperspace blades. That’s a very different matter from some regular sword.

Comment: Presumably getting stabbed by Hela hurts a lot more than being stabbed by some regular implement. After all, she is not a a queen, nor a monster - she is the god of death. Weren’t you listening? ;)

Comment: Given that no-one’s ever killed Thor, I guess we can’t really be sure. If INFINITY WAR SPOILERS Doctor Strange can come back to life and get the Time Stone back, maybe he can try 14 million or so different things and see what works?

Answer (score 4):

> "They seem to think us immortal. Shall we test that?" - Loki Laufeyson (The Avengers)

Right before Loki sends Thor plummeting towards the ground while in the containment unit meant for the Hulk, the look on both Thor and Loki's face indicates that if Thor had not gotten out when he did, he would have died. 
He can therefore obviously be harmed by excessive amounts of force.

That said, Thor comes from the Allfather bloodline, so he is naturally more powerful and can take more of a beating than other Asgardians.
Asgardians also do heal faster than humans, but Hela killed several Asgardian soldiers, so *I think he can be killed by Gods/Godesses/other beings with battle skills on par with his, provided he isn't healed, given a chance to recover, or damaged beyond recovery.*

Comment: Can you also give sources for "Asgardians heal faster than humans", please?

Comment: 'Even though they can survive tremendous amounts of superhuman physical punishment more than a normal human being, they can be hurt or damaged. That is when their advanced regenerative abilities take over. It enables them to heal much faster than an normal human being.' from http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Asgardians

Comment: @Kat:   Wikis are not primary sources