# Can Hela be killed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

Throughout the whole film *Thor: Ragnarok*, Hela was shown to be remarkably powerful. Decimating Asgard's army, Loki, and Thor, she has proven herself as being one the best villains in the MCU. With that being said, there were several occasions on which she should have been seriously injured but to no avail. She was thrust through by one of the Einherjar, thrust through by Valkyrie, and also hit by a very powerful lightning bolt from Thor. All of these seemed to have no effect on her.

So this leaves the question to be asked. Can Hela be killed?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that anything in the Marvel universe can be killed if you're patient and committed.

Comment: She *can* be, sure. It’s just that, like Hulk or even Thor himself, it’s not *easy*.

Comment: According to Odin the asguardians (of which hela is one) are not gods and can be killed all be it after much effort or a few thousand years. it is however possible that being a powerful sorcerer, the god of death and the ruler of hel (not a misspelling just norse) she has certain perks we don't know about and most asguardians aren't privy to but given that even odin can die it seems unlikely.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173522/in-the-mcu-what-can-kill-thor-and-what-cannot

Answer (score 14):

One very important plot point in Thor:Ragnarok is that Hela draws her power from Asgard itself. Odin's life-force kept her imprisoned temporarily, but he never actually killed her. Once Odin died, she was released, and became progressively more powerful the longer she stayed on Asgard.

As you could see from the first scene where Loki and Thor meet her, her costume appeared torn, but once she arrived in Asgard, the tears sealed up and she presumably healed from any wound she had received. So the main thing about her that made her so difficult to kill was that the longer she stayed on Asgard, the more powerful she became, so when Thor hit her with 'the biggest lightning bolt in the history of lightning', she was relatively unscathed.

However, that was why Thor and Loki realised they had to free Surtur to destroy Asgard in the end, and also why Hela said "No!" when she saw Surtur emerge. She then battled him for a bit before he completely destroyed Asgard. It stands to reason that once her source of power was destroyed, Hela would lose much of her power.

Of course, it would still be difficult to kill her. My guess is that with her main source of power gone, she would only be comparable to Loki, who emerged generally ok after getting beat up by the Hulk. But there's no reason that she *can't* be killed. Especially since Asgard is now gone.

In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if she *is* dead. Blown up along with Asgard.

Comment: She is dead, but not because Asgard got blown up. Surtur hit her with his sword. https://youtu.be/ikgrdea95f0?t=14m17s

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

- Too long for comment...
- If Odin can die...
- That said, we don't know her current status for sure...
- We also don't know what Asgard is...

So obviously, Asgardians can die. They have done it all throughout time. Odin's father and grandfather died, Friga died, Odin died... I have a hard time thinking that if they can die that Hela can't for some reason... I suspect that that if no other Asgard has been truly immortal up until this point that Hela is not as well.

That said, it is possible that she has discovered something that no other Asgardian has before. This I think leads to what your real question is: **What is her current status?**

When the "royal" family is imbued with abilities they become more than just a typical Asgardian. Thor, as we now know, has the power of thunder within him and does not need to call it from the sky or his hammer. Hes gots sparkles...

Hela is the God of death, Odin's executioner and really, really good at killing people. However, we don't know what her "innate" ability was. Perhaps in being the God of Death she has some strange ability that allows her to fully cheat death; similar to how the God of Thunder has control over lightning. And maybe that is why Odin couldn't kill her. My first assumption was that it was because he didn't want to kill his daughter and wanted to put her in timeout for a few millennia, but maybe it was that he actually couldn't do it.

Toward the end of the movie we see the people of Asgard escape and after we see that "those foundations are gone" Asgard appears to be completely obliterated. It was my assumption that she would have been destroyed then, even if she had leapt from the path of Surtur's blade when it came down or survived the blow somehow.

Again however, she draws her power from Asgard. But everybody constantly says that "Asgard is not a place, it is a people." So what Asgard does she draw her power from? Is it the place or the people? If Asgard is truly a people then what Hela draws her power from still exists... is that enough to have saved her?

Comment: We don't know her innate ability? She spent the entire movie generating melee and projectile weapons at will pretty much as soon as she appeared on screen, and often times in numerous batches or in very large sizes. In essence, the Goddess of Death can will an armory into existence.

Comment: @Ellesedil - So can Loki...

Comment: What? Loki carries some long daggers that he pulls out of concealment for battle. He can't manifest them with pure will. He throws one at Hela in the bifrost, and then uses only one dagger and his horn helmet in the final battle. Anything Loki does create is an illusion since that's his ability. Hela, on the other hand, creates hundreds of weapons during the course of the movie.